# ¿Como obtener la ruta de un archivo con el explorador de Windows en java?

Tags: java, windows

Mi problema es que al utilizar el File Chooser de Java no puedo pre-visualizar las fotos que deseo cargar a la base de datos y es muy importante porque manejo muchas. Así que deseo poder usar el explorador de windows para hacer esto ya que en el se puede poner iconos grandes o muy grandes y esto seria de gran ayuda. Espero su ayuda en verdad la necesito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es el [SWT's FileDialog](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/FileDialog.html), aquí tienes un [ejemplo](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet72.java) que aclara un poco su uso, en tu caso tengo entendido que quieres utilizarlo para "Abrir" no para "Guardar" y supongo que para manejar varios archivos, así que no te olvides de cambiar el código del ejemplo a:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    // Don't show the shell.
    // shell.open();  
    FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog (shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.MULTI);
    String[] filterNames = new String [] {"Todos los archivos (*)"};
    String[] filterExtensions = new String [] {"*"};
    String filterPath = "c:\\";
    dialog.setFilterNames (filterNames);
    dialog.setFilterExtensions (filterExtensions);
    dialog.setFilterPath (filterPath);
    dialog.open();
    System.out.println ("Selected files: ");
    String[] selectedFileNames = dialog.getFileNames();

    for(String fileName : selectedFileNames) {
        System.out.println("  " + fileName);
    }

    shell.close();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

Para modificar los filtros de archivos aceptados debes modificar las siguientes líneas, en este caso vamos a permitir sólo archivos JPEG o PNG:

```
String[] filterNames = new String [] {"JPEG (*.jpg)", "PNG (*.png)"};
String[] filterExtensions = new String [] {"*.jpg", "*.png"};
```

Y esto no lo he probado pero debería funcionar también, ofrecería 3 opciones, Todas las imagenes, JPEG y PNG:

```
String[] filterNames = new String [] {"Todas las imagenes (*.jpg, *.png)", "JPEG (*.jpg)", "PNG (*.png)"};
String[] filterExtensions = new String [] {"*.jpg|*.png", "*.jpg", "*.png"};
```

Comment: Si, exactamente eso era lo que buscaba muchas muchas gracias. Pero, ¿y si solo deseo cargar ciertas extensiones? como JPG O PNG

Comment: @ArturoCarrilloFernández He modificado la respuesta para que lo veas mejor, está en la parte final, sólo tienes que cambiar esas 2 líneas

Comment: Muchas gracias @Dekadence pero no me deja agregar los filtros, pero ya me ayudaste bastante.

Comment: @ArturoCarrilloFernández ten en cuenta que están en el ejemplo que yo te puse, tienes que reemplazar las anteriores y deben ir antes de dialog.setFilterNames y dialog.setFilterExtensions